# Calculate the bounding box from a list of points using Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Given a list of points

```
[
  %{ x: 3, y: 8 },
  ...,
  %{ x: 1, y: 4 }
]
```

What is the best way to calculate the coordinates of a box that will contain all points - i.e. the bounds: `%{ x1: 1, y1: 4, x2: 3, y2: 8 }`

I have a hunch I can use [`Enum.flat_map_reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map_reduce/3) but the syntax is baffling me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ran into this as part of Advent of Code 2018 day 10 last year. [This was my method](https://github.com/adamu/AdventOfCode2018/blob/master/day10/day10.exs#L30). It sets the bounding box to the initial point, and then expands it as it finds points further out. No need for `nil`. :-)

Here it is adapted for your data:

```elixir
# Start with the first point, then compare all the others to find the extremities
def bounding_box([%{x: x, y: y} | points]) do
  Enum.reduce(points, %{x1: x, y1: y, x2: x, y2: y}, fn point, box ->
    %{
      x1: min(point.x, box.x1),
      y1: min(point.y, box.y1),
      x2: max(point.x, box.x2),
      y2: max(point.y, box.y2)
    }
  end)
end
```

Comment: Nice, I find this more readable than Aleksei's solution, although I guess the inner fn arguments in that answer could also be renamed 'point' and 'box' which would help. Would this work just the same if the outer function was: def bounding_box([%{x: x, y: y} | points]) do ...

Comment: Thanks :) You're right. When I originally wrote it, I thought about that but assumed it wouldn't work in the case of the single element, because it would be passing an empty list to `Enum.reduce/3`. But in that case, `reduce` still returns the initial accumulator value, so it's a good simplification. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3) would be enough.

```rb
input = [%{x: 3, y: 8}, %{x: 1, y: 4}]

Enum.reduce(input, %{x1: nil, x2: nil, y1: nil, y2: nil}, fn
  %{x: x, y: y}, %{x1: x1, x2: x2, y1: y1, y2: y2} ->
    %{
      x1: if(x < x1, do: x, else: x1),
      x2: if(is_nil(x2) or x > x2, do: x, else: x2),
      y1: if(y < y1, do: y, else: y1),
      y2: if(is_nil(y2) or y > y2, do: y, else: y2),
    }
end)
```

A number in *Erlang* (and hence *Elixir*) is *less* than any other type, hence nils for `x1` and `y1` are simply fine. For `x2` and `y2` we require an additional condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this, as more readable than an `Enum.reduce`:

```
input = [%{x: 3, y: 8}, %{x: 1, y: 4}]

%{
  x1: input |> Enum.map(& &1.x) |> Enum.min(),
  x2: input |> Enum.map(& &1.x) |> Enum.max(),
  y1: input |> Enum.map(& &1.y) |> Enum.min(),
  y2: input |> Enum.map(& &1.y) |> Enum.max()
}
```

Of course there is the downside of iterating over the list multiple times. Depending on your exact requirements, that might be a problem.

Comment: [`Enum.min_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#min_by/3) and [`Enum.max_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#max_by/3) at least do not produce 2 intermediate redundant lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Enum.reduce/3` is the right way to go, but `Kernel.min/2` and `Kernel.max/2` can handle the decision logic pretty well (we just have to augment `max` to reject `nil`)

```
defmodule BoundingBox do
  @moduledoc """
  Creates a bounding box around coordinates.
  """
  @initial %{x1: nil, y1: nil, x2: nil, y2: nil}

  def new(enumerable) do
    Enum.reduce(enumerable, @initial, &get_bounds/2)
  end

  defp get_bounds(%{x: x, y: y}, %{x1: left, y1: bottom, x2: right, y2: top}) do
    %{x1: min(left, x), y1: min(bottom, y), x2: max_num(right, x), y2: max_num(top, right)}
  end

  defp max_num(nil, b), do: b
  defp max_num(a, b), do: max(a, b)
end
```